# How is the source link-layer address in IPv6 router solicitation(RS) messages used?

Tags: ipv6

When I analyze the router solicitation(RS) messages, then they contain the MAC address of the sending host. How does the router use this MAC address seen in ICMPv6 message? Does it simply use it as a destination MAC address for RA message? Is there any other use for source link-layer address in IPv6 router solicitation(RS) message?

Comment: AFAIK the only use for it is for the router to update its own neighbor cache.